# Playframework Render Javadocs

Tags: java, playframework-2.2

I need to render an entire javadocs filestructure which is in plain html.
I need this to render the files using permissions. The user needs to be logged in in order to view the files.

I got a folder with .js .html and some other folders as well. I need these to be viewed by a user, but only if this user is logged in.

- How do I allow Play! to return a set of these specific files, without having to modify them?

Googled quite a lot but to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need some more details here or no one will be able to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create your own version of the assets controller that will enforce the auth-requirement, you could probably get it to work by just wrapping the built in Assets controller. If the javadoc is not packaged with play you could take a look at the ExternalAssets controller which can server arbitrary files from the filesystem.

If you do not already have a play app that you are including this in it would probably be easier to do this with a webserver, apache would for example allow you to do this with only configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will further investigate this and see if I can come up with some sort of solution.

Comment: It worked! It seems like others did not understand my question quite. I work for a company that has their own SDK with a documentation. The documentation which is generated using some javadoc generator is located in a filestructure just like a standalone website. I needed to render this separate website which worked file using GET  /docs/*file   controllers.ExternalAssets.at(path="documentation/", file)